# Calling jQuery plugin public function within plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know, there are quite a few examples on the Web, but finding real one out of them all is tough for beginner. So I want to create jQuery plugin with public methods. Example code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.peel = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
        };

        var settings = $.extend({},defaults, options);

        this.public = function() {
            alert("public");
        };

        var private = function() {
            alert("private");
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            //this.public();
            private();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

As I found, this is the way to make public function, which could be called like this :

```
var peel = $('img').peel();
peel.public();
```

So far it works as expected - public() can be called. But what if i want to call that function within my plugin? I commented out in this.each() because it does not work. How can i achieve that?

Comment: try examples show in jQuery Docs  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

One way to create publicly accessible methods within your plugins is to use the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory).  This is the framework that jQuery UI uses for all of it's supported UI widgets.  A quick example would look like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "something.mywidget", {

    // Set up the widget
    _create: function() {

    },

    publicFunction: function(){
        //...
    }
  });
}( jQuery ) );

var $w = $('#someelement').mywidget();

$w.mywidget('publicFunction');
```

Comment: assumes OP is using jQUeryUI, `best way` likely better phrased as `one way`